# How to map TypeScript ES6 default imports to return values of AMD modules?

Tags: javascript, typescript, amd

For example, I have an AMD module in vanilla JS (not touched by `tsc`):

```
// Foo.js
define([], function() {
  return class Foo {}
})
```

with accompanying declaration file:

```
// Foo.d.ts
declare class Foo {
  // ...
}

export default Foo
```

then I have a typescript module:

```
// app.ts
import Foo from './Foo'
new Foo // Uncaught TypeError: Foo_1.default is not a constructor
```

When I compile my typescript module to AMD format with `tsc` and run it in my RequireJS environment, there's an error that `default` is undefined because typescript compiles to:

```
define("app", ["require", "exports", "Foo"], function (require, exports, Foo_1) {
    "use strict";
    console.log(Foo_1["default"]);
});
```

I don't want it to grab the `default` property. I want it to treat a default import like it is simply grabbing the returned value of my define module. Every single module in my project is a `define()` module, or a typescript module compiled to `define()` (AMD). I'd simply like to get that return object.

Is there a way to do (configure) this?

EDIT:

I know I can `import * as Foo from './Foo'`, but that is sort of hacky, and it generates errors because the declared module doesn't have named exports. I would like a non-error way to do it, if possible.

EDIT: I learned I can just do

```
// app.ts
import Foo = require('./Foo')
new Foo // no error
```

to achieve the result. The only problem with that is it is not ES6-compatible. This means that if we tell typescript to leave ES6 import statements as-is, then other tools won't understand typescript-specific import/export statements. I need a way to use only official ES6 module syntax in a reasonable way.

I'm think that my solution might be to just do a post-tsc-compile transform step to convert default import access points.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import * as Foo from './Foo'
```

Comment: That's a funny way to get Foo. If I have `tsc` ignore errors and still emit a bundle, that works. But there's errors because the `.d.ts` file looks the way it does (see the updated question). Any more suggestions?

Comment: Oh, I suppose the `import Foo = require('./Foo')` works, but it's not ES6, so if the code is ever used in other environments where TS only compiles language but leaves module syntax alone, it won't work. Or will it?